# Why do spans break differently depending on space between element definitions?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Why does it matter to element layout that a space or newline exists between them?

E.g. `<span/><span/>` behaves differently from `<span/> <span/>` (note the space).

What I'm trying to solve to have my span elements line break but also not have a visible space when they don't break. In below snippet you can see span-pairs defined within first a wide then a narrow paragraph, and the first example that does not use any spacing does not linebreak like the others do.

Why is that? Is there a term I can google to learn more? How can I have two spans always linebreak when their container is narrow **AND** not have visible space between them when the container is wide enough?

```css
p {
  width: 135px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.narrow {
  width: 35px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 140%;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  No space:
</h1>

<p>
  <span>Foo</span><span>Bar</span>
</p>
<p class="narrow">
  <span>Foo</span><span>Bar</span>
</p>

<h1>
  Space between element definitions:
</h1>

<p>
  <span>Foo</span> <span>Bar</span>
</p>
<p class="narrow">
  <span>Foo</span> <span>Bar</span>
</p>

<h1>
  New line between element definitions:
</h1>

<p>
  <span>Foo</span>
  <span>Bar</span>
</p>
<p class="narrow">
  <span>Foo</span>
  <span>Bar</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This space is called a **white space** it's like a space you put between two words. So `this is a text` is different from `thisisatext` and `span` is an inline element so it behaves like text.

To remove them you can set font-size to 0:

```css
p {
  width: 135px;
  background-color: pink;
  font-size:0;
}

.narrow {
  width: 35px;
  font-size:0;
}
span {
 font-size:initial;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 140%;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  No space:
</h1>

<p>
  <span>Foo</span><span>Bar</span>
</p>
<p class="narrow">
  <span>Foo</span><span>Bar</span>
</p>

<h1>
  Space between element definitions:
</h1>

<p>
  <span>Foo</span> <span>Bar</span>
</p>
<p class="narrow">
  <span>Foo</span> <span>Bar</span>
</p>

<h1>
  New line between element definitions:
</h1>

<p>
  <span>Foo</span>
  <span>Bar</span>
</p>
<p class="narrow">
  <span>Foo</span>
  <span>Bar</span>
</p>
```

And in case you want to avoid the line-break you can consider the property `white-space` and set it to `nowrap`:

```css
p {
  width: 135px;
  background-color: pink;
  font-size:0;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.narrow {
  width: 35px;
  font-size:0;
}
span {
 font-size:initial;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 140%;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  No space:
</h1>

<p>
  <span>Foo</span><span>Bar</span>
</p>
<p class="narrow">
  <span>Foo</span><span>Bar</span>
</p>

<h1>
  Space between element definitions:
</h1>

<p>
  <span>Foo</span> <span>Bar</span>
</p>
<p class="narrow">
  <span>Foo</span> <span>Bar</span>
</p>

<h1>
  New line between element definitions:
</h1>

<p>
  <span>Foo</span>
  <span>Bar</span>
</p>
<p class="narrow">
  <span>Foo</span>
  <span>Bar</span>
</p>
```